# SqlException error when trying to implement pagination in .net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pagination, entity-framework-core

I have these two pieces of code to implement pagination.

The first one is a class as follows:

```
public class QueryParameters
{
    const int _maxSize = 100;
    private int _size = 50;

    public int Page { get; set; }

    public int Size 
    {  
        get { return _size; }
        set { _size = Math.Min(_maxSize, value); }
    }
}
```

The second one is my HttpGet code:

```
    private readonly NSContext _context;

    public UsersController(NSContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllUSers([FromQuery] QueryParameters queryParameters)
    {
        IQueryable<User> users = _context.User;
        users = users
            .Skip(queryParameters.Size * (queryParameters.Page - 1))
            .Take(queryParameters.Size);
        return Ok(await users.ToArrayAsync());
    }
```

But when I run the program I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Try give **Page** property a [Range(1, int.MaxValue)] attribute for client side validation, or manually adjust `if Page is 0 then set Page  = 1 ` for server side tolerance.

Comment: Guess: your frontend uses 0 to denote the first page. What happens when `queryParameters.Page` is 0? You subtract 1 and the argument becomes negative. It's used directly as argument for `OFFSET` and then the error. If that's the case then change your frontend to use 1 OR check default values in `QueryParameters` (in case the frontend makes a request without a value for that) OR do not subtract 1.

Comment: Debug and verify that "queryParameters.Page" does not become zero. But, in general your code should ensure that "queryParameters.Page" does not become zero since that results in  "-queryParameters.Size"

Comment: You need to make **absolutely sure** that the value for `.Skip()` never is negative; right now, with `.Skip(queryParameters.Size * (queryParameters.Page - 1))` - if your `Page` value is 0, then you get a result of `-queryParameters.Size` and this is not allowed....

Comment: You're right. Be deleting -1 from this command <code>(queryParameters.Page -1)<code>, problem got solved. 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is you are trying to skip negative 50 (-50) rows
thats ie,
The PAGE variable in QueryParameters Class is 0, because you have not initialized it any where

so this statement

```
 Skip(queryParameters.Size * (queryParameters.Page - 1))
```

says Skip(50 * (0 - 1)) which is Skip (-50)

That's why the error.

You can give a default value

If you are using C# 6 you can do this:

```
public int Page { get; set; } = 1
```

or

```
private int _Page = 1;
public int Page
{
   get
   {
      return _Page;
   }
   set
   {
      _Page = value;
   }
}
```

I hope this solves your issue